# usage of cors middleware vs custom middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, backend, middleware

Pardon me for this stupid question, but can someone explain me how the cors middleware work?

I accidentally called an *auth* middleware by adding brackets after it and it ran that middleware without even me requesting to that route.

I know that adding brackets after function invokes it but what is it with cors middleware that we add those brackets after it??

**usage of cors middleware from docs:**

```
app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
})
```

**using auth middleware with () gives error:**

```
app.get('/products/:id', auth(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is an authorized Route'})
})
```

**usage of auth middleware without () works fine:**

```
app.get('/products/:id', auth, function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is an authorized Route'})
})
```

Comment: does calling `cors()` return a `function` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can [return other functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function#example_return_a_function), when you call the `cors` function using `cors()`, you get back a [new function](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js#L192), that is used as the middleware function in `app.get()`. Your `cors()` example could be rewritten like so:

```js
const corsMiddlewareFn = cors();
app.get('/products/:id', corsMiddlewareFn, function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
})
```

Above we store the function that calling `cors()` returns in a variable called `corsMiddlewareFn`, and then we use that as middleware as part of the call to `app.get()`. Having `cors()` return a function is useful as it allows us to pass options to the `cors()` function so that the middleware function it returns can use those options accordingly.

On the other hand, your `auth` function most likely doesn't return a function, so `auth` itself is the middleware function you want to use, and not its return value which you would get when calling `auth()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `cors` module returns a function that takes optional configuration and returns the middleware.

The `auth` is already the middleware, not a function, so no need to call it.